# How to write a c program which has a large code section

Tags: c

I need to have a C program having a large code segment size (at least some MB)
I want to check out some behavior.

**Here is the scenario :**

Run two processes:

Process A: One having a large code segment size resided in the system RAM

Process B: which just eats up the system RAM ( a simple malloc+memset ).

Notice whether the resident set size of the process A decreases or some of its pages are swiped out or not before the exhaustion of the memory.
When I write a simple program the code segment size remains within the boundary of 1 page (4KB).

Comment: You should probably specify which operating system you want to do this on.

Comment: @R - No its not - meta tags are [officially dead](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/)

Answer (score 2):

If it can be assembly instead of C: (using gnu as)

```
.text
.space 0x7FFFFFFF
```

though i wouldn't recommend going quite so large

Answer (score 1):

If you write in C++ - I can advise you using templates.

For example:

```
template <int i>
struct PlainOfCode
{
    template <int j>
    static int Worker(int x)
    {
        return j ^ (x + i) ^ Worker<j-1>(x+j);
    }

    template <>
    static int Worker<0>(int x) { return x; }

    static int Batch(int x)
    {
        return PlainOfCode<i-1>::Batch(x) ^ Worker<i*i>(x);
    }
};

template <>
struct PlainOfCode<0>
{
    static int Batch(int x)
    {
        return x;
    }
};

// main
int j = PlainOfCode<30>::Batch(GetTickCount());
if (25 != j)
    GetTickCount();
```

This generates enormous implicit function count (and hence - code size).
Disable all the optimizations.

Comment: The code looks pretty impressive, but g++ 3.4.4 fails to compile it. It says: `largecode.cc:10: error: invalid explicit specialization before '>' token`.

Answer (score 1):

On Linux and compatible systems, you could probably use `mmap()` to allocate some code-space, and then fill it with whatever you feel like (maybe just 1 MB of `NOP`s), then call it to make sure it really gets added to your code space.

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by the C++ meta programming, I figured, just generate a large C source code from a C program. Change the "max" variable to how many functions you want. When you compile and run this code, it will create a C program called `largefile.c`. Compile this program, with optimizations turned off. It might be a good idea to remove the generated printfs too, it depends on what you want to do I guess. Good luck!

```
#include <stdio.h>

void writefunc(FILE *fp, int i)
{
    fprintf(fp, "void f%d()\n{\n\tprintf(\"%d\\n\");\n\tf%d();\n}\n", i, i, i+1);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    FILE *fp = fopen("largecode.c", "w");
    int i;
    int max = 100;

    fprintf(fp, "#include<stdio.h>\n");

    fprintf(fp, "\nint f%d()\n{\n}\n", max + 1);

    for (i = max; i > 0; i--) {
        writefunc(fp, i);
    }

    fprintf(fp, "\nint main(int argc, char** argv){\n\tf1();\n}\n");

    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to write a program with large code segment, you can just borrow source code of any relatively large open source software, it is bound to have decent code segment size.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to generate large sections of repetitive code using macros. For example, the following is a C program (can also be compiled with a c++ compiler) with a large code segment:

```
volatile int x; // "volatile" to forbid compiler optimization

#define DO_0 ++x;
#define DO_1 {DO_0; DO_0; DO_0; DO_0; DO_0; DO_0; DO_0; DO_0; DO_0; DO_0}
#define DO_2 {DO_1; DO_1; DO_1; DO_1; DO_1; DO_1; DO_1; DO_1; DO_1; DO_1}
#define DO_3 {DO_2; DO_2; DO_2; DO_2; DO_2; DO_2; DO_2; DO_2; DO_2; DO_2}
#define DO_4 {DO_3; DO_3; DO_3; DO_3; DO_3; DO_3; DO_3; DO_3; DO_3; DO_3}
#define DO_5 {DO_4; DO_4; DO_4; DO_4; DO_4; DO_4; DO_4; DO_4; DO_4; DO_4}
#define DO_6 {DO_5; DO_5; DO_5; DO_5; DO_5; DO_5; DO_5; DO_5; DO_5; DO_5}
#define DO_7 {DO_6; DO_6; DO_6; DO_6; DO_6; DO_6; DO_6; DO_6; DO_6; DO_6}
#define DO_8 {DO_7; DO_7; DO_7; DO_7; DO_7; DO_7; DO_7; DO_7; DO_7; DO_7}
#define DO_9 {DO_8; DO_8; DO_8; DO_8; DO_8; DO_8; DO_8; DO_8; DO_8; DO_8}

int main()
{
    DO_6; // do trivial stuff 1 million times
}
```

This gives a pretty precise control on the size of the code segment. For example, on my system the size of the `main` function is 15000006 bytes (each `DO_0` generates 15 bytes).

P.S. Just realized the question was asked 3 years ago.